# Lifelines Hazard Ratio = 1 for all covariates

Tags: python, python-3.x, cox-regression, lifelines

I'm running the following using the lifelines package:

```
cph = CoxPHFitter()
cph.fit(data, duration_col='T', event_col='vital_status', show_progress=True)
cph.print_summary()
```

However I'm getting all Hazard ratios equal to 1 (exp(coef) and the same for the confidence intervals

```
                   coef    exp(coef)   se(coef)    coef lower 95%   coef upper 95% exp(coef) lower 95% exp(coef) upper 95%
                                                                                                  
                    0.00      1.00      0.00           -0.00            0.00                1.00                1.00
                   -0.00      1.00      0.00           -0.00           -0.00                1.00                1.00
                   -0.00      1.00      0.00           -0.00            0.00                1.00                1.00
                   -0.00      1.00      0.00           -0.00            0.00                1.00                1.00
                   -0.00      1.00      0.00           -0.00            0.00                1.00                1.00
                    0.00      1.00      0.00           -0.00            0.00                1.00                1.00
                    0.00      1.00      0.00           -0.01            0.01                0.99                1.01
                   -0.00      1.00      0.00           -0.00            0.00                1.00                1.00
                    0.00      1.00      0.00           -0.00            0.00                1.00                1.00
                    0.00      1.00      0.00           -0.00            0.00                1.00                1.00
                    0.00      1.00      0.00           -0.00            0.00                1.00                1.00
                    0.00      1.00      0.00           -0.00            0.00                1.00                1.00
                   -0.00      1.00      0.00           -0.00            0.00                1.00                1.00
                   -0.00      1.00      0.00           -0.00            0.00                1.00                1.00
                   -0.00      1.00      0.00           -0.00            0.00                1.00                1.00
```

Have I gone wrong somewhere? How likely is it that all Hazard Ratios should be exactly 1?

Thanks
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aI6sZ.png

Comment: Please do not upload images of text. [SO added support for tables as of Dec. 2020](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support)

Comment: @Agustin, I suspect that it's rounding to 1.0. Try `cph.print_summary(decimals=10)`. Anyways, is it possible that your covariates are totally unrelated to your survival time?

Comment: Thank you, yes it is possible, I was just surprised. I've checked the R survival package and got very similar results, so it must be the case.
Thanks!